# What is the shortcut to toggle fullscreen to windowed?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I accidentally pressed some key combination that caused Batman: Arkham City to enter fullscreen mode from borderless windowed mode. Because I don't know what key combination caused it, I restarted the game to fix it, which is tedious. What caused Arkham City to do this? What key combination?

Comment: Alt and enter perhaps?

Comment: @TZHX Yup, that's it. Perhaps I should rephrase the question to be more general?

Comment: Most Direct3D 10 and 11 games should support ALT-Enter to switch between windowed and full screen mode, as it's handled by Direct3D. Some Direct3D 10/11 games may choose disable this however. Games using Direct3D 9 or earlier have to handle ALT-Enter themselves, making it less commonly supported with these games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alt+Enter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182023/what-is-the-shortcut-to-toggle-fullscreen-to-windowed#comment246182_182023) (at least on the Windows OS). This answer is not trivial, this answer is not trivial, [THIS ANSWER IS NOT TRIVIAL](https://www.youtube.com/embed/DRaLpHoZA8E?autoplay=1&start=10&end=19)!

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as correct then?

Comment: > This answer is not trivial 

???

Comment: @Gal I think I added that because without those, the system thinks that the answer is too small and doesn't allow it to be posted.